# How to connect boxplots with a mean line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

The following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_dict = {'Best fit': [395.0, 401.0, 358.0, 443.0, 357.0, 378.0, 356.0, 356.0, 403.0, 380.0, 397.0, 406.0, 409.0, 414.0, 350.0, 433.0, 345.0, 376.0, 374.0, 379.0, 9.0, 13.0, 10.0, 13.0, 16.0, 12.0, 6.0, 11.0, 20.0, 10.0, 12.0, 11.0, 15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 18.0, 864.0, 803.0, 849.0, 858.0, 815.0, 856.0, 927.0, 878.0, 834.0, 837.0, 811.0, 857.0, 848.0, 869.0, 861.0, 820.0, 887.0, 842.0, 834.0, np.nan], 'MDP': [332, 321, 304, 377, 304, 313, 289, 314, 341, 321, 348, 334, 361, 348, 292, 362, 285, 316, 291, 318, 3, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 8, 6, 4, 0, 8, 1, 4, 0, 9, 5, 3, 8, 770, 770, 819, 751, 822, 842, 758, 825, 886, 830, 774, 839, 779, 821, 812, 850, 822, 786, 874, 831], 'Q-Learning': [358, 329, 309, 381, 302, 319, 296, 315, 343, 318, 338, 336, 360, 357, 299, 363, 287, 337, 301, 334, 3, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 8, 6, 4, 0, 8, 1, 4, 0, 9, 5, 3, 8, 771, 833, 757, 837, 831, 784, 806, 890, 843, 775, 838, 776, 824, 830, 834, 827, 791, 868, 816, 806], 'parametrized_factor': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

# figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

# melt the dataframe into a long form
dfm = data.melt(id_vars='parametrized_factor')

# plot
ax = sns.boxplot(data=dfm, x='variable', y='value', hue='parametrized_factor', linewidth=0.7, palette="Set3")

ax.yaxis.grid(True) # Hide the horizontal gridlines
ax.xaxis.grid(True) # Show the vertical gridlines
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

# ADDED: Remove labels.
ax.set_ylabel('Rejection ratio')    
ax.set_xlabel('')

plt.show()
```

Plots the following:

[image]

Is there a way to connect, for example, the 'Best Fit', 'MDP and 'Q-Learning' for every legend category?

In other words, how to connect same color boxplots by a line connecting its mean values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a point plot and recalculate the dodge width.  For a box plot, there are 3 boxes equally spread over the default distance of 0.8.  For a pointplot, the lines are put at the limits of the width, so a scaling is needed to make them fit the boxplots. See [this github issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2528) for extra information.

Note that you don't need to calculate the means, as that is the [default estimator for `pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html). Error bars for the mean can be suppressed with `ci=None`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_dict = {'Best fit': [395.0, 401.0, 358.0, 443.0, 357.0, 378.0, 356.0, 356.0, 403.0, 380.0, 397.0, 406.0, 409.0, 414.0, 350.0, 433.0, 345.0, 376.0, 374.0, 379.0, 9.0, 13.0, 10.0, 13.0, 16.0, 12.0, 6.0, 11.0, 20.0, 10.0, 12.0, 11.0, 15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 18.0, 864.0, 803.0, 849.0, 858.0, 815.0, 856.0, 927.0, 878.0, 834.0, 837.0, 811.0, 857.0, 848.0, 869.0, 861.0, 820.0, 887.0, 842.0, 834.0, np.nan], 'MDP': [332, 321, 304, 377, 304, 313, 289, 314, 341, 321, 348, 334, 361, 348, 292, 362, 285, 316, 291, 318, 3, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 8, 6, 4, 0, 8, 1, 4, 0, 9, 5, 3, 8, 770, 770, 819, 751, 822, 842, 758, 825, 886, 830, 774, 839, 779, 821, 812, 850, 822, 786, 874, 831], 'Q-Learning': [358, 329, 309, 381, 302, 319, 296, 315, 343, 318, 338, 336, 360, 357, 299, 363, 287, 337, 301, 334, 3, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 8, 6, 4, 0, 8, 1, 4, 0, 9, 5, 3, 8, 771, 833, 757, 837, 831, 784, 806, 890, 843, 775, 838, 776, 824, 830, 834, 827, 791, 868, 816, 806], 'parametrized_factor': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

dfm = data.melt(id_vars='parametrized_factor')

ax = sns.boxplot(data=dfm, x='variable', y='value', hue='parametrized_factor', linewidth=0.7, palette="Set3")
sns.pointplot(data=dfm, x='variable', y='value', hue='parametrized_factor', ci=None,
              dodge=.8 - .8 / 3, scale=0.3, color='black', marker='D')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[:4], labels=labels[:3] + ["means"], title="parametrized factor",
          bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1.02), loc='upper left')

ax.set_ylabel('Rejection ratio')
ax.set_xlabel('')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pointplot to connect means]

Answer (score 2):

- Calculate the mean for each group, and then add them to the existing `ax` with a `seaborn.lineplot`
- Set `dodge=False` in the `seaborn.boxplot`
- Remember that the line in the boxplot is the median, not the mean.

  - Add the means to `boxplot` with `showmeans=True`, and then remove `marker='o'` from the `lineplot`, if desired.
- As pointed out [JohanC's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67976244/7758804):

  - `sns.pointplot(data=dfm, x='variable', y='value', hue='parametrized_factor', ax=ax)` can be used without the need for calculating `dfm_mean`, however there isn't a `legend=False` parameter, which then requires manually managing the legend.
  - Also, I think it's more straightforward to use `dodge=False` than to calculate the offsets.
  - Either answer is viable, depending on your requirements.

```py
# calculate the mean for each group and convert to long format with melt
dfm_mean = data.groupby('parametrized_factor', as_index=False).mean().melt(id_vars='parametrized_factor')

# plot
# figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

# create the boxplot but set dodge to false, so all plots are on the same x-axis line
ax = sns.boxplot(data=dfm, x='variable', y='value', hue='parametrized_factor', linewidth=0.7, palette="Set3", dodge=False)

# plot a line plot with markers for the means
sns.lineplot(data=dfm_mean, x='variable', y='value', hue='parametrized_factor', marker='o', ax=ax, legend=False)

# set the legend outside
ax.legend(title='Factor', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

- If `dodge` isn't `False` the result is:

[image]